# Converting a datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

So I'm trying to convert this date but it doesn't really seem to work. What can the problem be? The Birthday has datetime as datetime!

```
INSERT Info
(Name, Birthday)
VALUES('Sara', CONVERT(datetime, 12-12-2015, 105));
```

This is the error message I get "Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
CONVERT(datetime, '12-12-2015', 105)
```

Without the quotes, SQL Server will interpret the expression as 12 minus 12 minus 2015.

or you can omit `CONVERT` and let SQL Server do the conversion implicitly:

```
INSERT Info
(Name, Birthday)
VALUES('Sara', '12-12-2015');
```

Comment: Crap, how couldn't I see that. Thanks you!